# Travis build works for python>=3.4 but fails for all python<=3.3 versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm building and testing my project with Travis CI. The build works perfectly for python>=3.4 but fails for versions <=3.3

Here is my log error:

```
Downloading archive: https://storage.googleapis.com/travis-ci-language-archives/python/binaries/ubuntu/16.04/x86_64/python-3.3.tar.bz2
0.10s$ curl -sSf --retry 5 -o python-3.3.tar.bz2 ${archive_url}
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Unable to download 3.3 archive. The archive may not exist. Please consider a different version.
```

Here is the [travis link](https://travis-ci.com/github/nidhaloff/deep-translator/jobs/368363419), where you can check my travis file and other configs.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. There are many threads on Github discussing this but there is no clear answer about how to solve this.

Comment: You can see by going to the URL yourself that it is indeed not there. Per https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/#python-versions they don't support Python 3.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial, 18.04 would be [`dist: bionic`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/bionic)).

Comment: I tried it on bionic now and it still showing the same error

Comment: Well see the same list.

Comment: Sorry I still dont get it. I just tried running with python3.1, which is supported (exits in the list) and it failed with the same error. Am I missing something? I'm writing 3.1 in my travis file to test with py3.1, I think I don't have to write the whole version as in the list (python-3.10-dev.tar.bz2) or am I wrong?

Comment: 3.1 is different to 3.10... If you want this to work, *use a combination that table says is supported*.

Comment: Alright thanks I will check out the travis docs for combination